# Free movement of worms vs siloed containment

Tags: compost, vermicomposting

Is there a benefit to free range worms over battery worms?  i.e. At present my worms live inside a couple of bins (one inside the other, with small holes for aeration and drainage, whilst keeping the worms sealed inside to do their work / as there's no contact with the soil in the location we had available for them.

We're about to move somewhere where I have the option to put my wormery in contact with the ground, so worms can come up when attracted to the food source, or freely leave when conditions aren't to their liking.

Is there a significant benefit to either of these approaches (e.g. does allowing them to vote with their feet (setae?) lead to healthier worms, or does concentrating them in one location help to focus their efforts)?

The worms are a mix of *Tiger Worms*, *Dendrobaena* and *Brandlings*. We're based in the UK, if that's a factor.

Comment: I wouldn't let them all leave, maybe handfuls at a time in order to make sure you have enough worms to keep the bin always alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some elements in favor of containment:

- It favors mating
- It avoids offering a worm feast to moles

In favor of free-range:

- they can escape if the compost temperature gets too high for them to survive